# What is the purpose of BAV70 in this schematic?

Tags: diodes

I've found this schematic for an Arduino board:

[image]

What is the purpose of the two diodes (BAV70) in these two applications?

---

2021 addendum (RGB)

This is Sparkfun's Arduino [Mini 05](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/11303) which is based on an ATMega328. Full schematic [here](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/arduino_mini_schematic05.pdf).

[image: Mini 05 schematic]
(click image to see it full size)

Comment: Which Arduino board? What is the RESET connected to?

Answer (score 2):

If you read 9.2.2.4 of the data sheet for the [LP2985](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp2985-n.pdf) it talks about protecting the output pin from reverse current flowing into it when the power input falls low. The two diodes (wired in parallel) will prevent this from happening and therefore protect the device from latching up: -

> if the output is pulled above the input, this diode (an internal diode) will turn ON and
>   current will flow into the regulator output. In such cases, a
>   parasitic SCR can latch which will allow a high current to flow into
>   VIN (and out the ground pin), which can damage the part.

As for the two diodes and the reset circuitry there isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Sorry to reawaken this old answer but maybe more can be said here than ask a near duplicate question. (1) The BAV70 is a dual *switching* diode but the schematic shows a *schottky?* - The BAV70 has max Vf of 1.25 V at it's max rating of 150 mA -- so why that and not something with lower Vf? (2) The "Mini 05" schematic shows RESET connected to the reset pin of a ATMega328 - which is also connected to a reset switch to GND and a 10K pullup to VCC. I'm not sure what the BAV70 there does. Any chance of revisiting this answer?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick about the OP: Joined 6 years, 3 months ago, last seen 5 years, 7 months ago. Also, what do you mean when you say this: *maybe more can be said here than ask a near duplicate question*???

Comment: I am using an old Mini 05 (since it was lying around) and had almost the same question. Before asking a new question I did a search for existing answers and found this. At the time this was asked, the OP didn't provide enough information for you to answer the question fully (at least that's how I interpret the last sentence of your answer). I was wondering why the schematic shows a Schottky when the BAV70 isn't a Schottky. Like OP, I wondered what might be the purpose of the BAV70 associated with the ATMega328 RESET. I could have just asked a new question but felt it best to avoid a duplicate?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick as for it not being Schottky, you just can't trust people making schematics to use the correct symbol for a non-Schottky device. As for the diodes on the reset circuit, I bet that's because of the possibility of the reset switch conducting ESD from users to the reset line and, of course, the diodes will offer some protection (more so if they were Schottky types).

Comment: Thanks. In retrospect it would probably have been clearer for everyone  if I'd just asked a new Q.   Maybe with a reference to this.  :-)